# Why I'm not able to run npm scripts?

Tags: laravel, npm

I've been using npm for 2 years now, and I just went through it today and I saw a problem.

There is no error in console when I run npm scripts but it doesn't do anything.

It just starts and ends in one or two second whatever I run.

[image]

Here is a example `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
}
```

There is no problem with what it's inside into the scripts but I have the problem with running them because they stop running in one second.

> EDIT: I've also tried this problem with react. When I run `npm start` this script also isn't going to be executed by npm.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Re-install node and npm

Comment: @FunkyMonk91 I just tried and it didn't work.

Comment: what does `npm -v` say?

Comment: @azium When I run npm -v in my machine I got this version 6.13.1

Comment: does `npm run hot` do anything differently?

Comment: @azium I tried it too but that also didn't work.

Comment: @RobC When I run this command into React project, I got this error :```npm ERR!  missing script: node_modules```. When I run it on my laravel project I got this:```npm ERR! missing script: app```.

Comment: You say _"When I run this command into React project"_ - what command ?

Comment: ```npm run *```

Comment: The errors you are now encountering, i.e. _"npm ERR! missing script: node_modules"_ and _"npm ERR! missing script: app"_, are a new different issue to what you described in your question. I suggest you [ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).